# Get random array for each categories chosen

Tags: java, android, arrays

i have a problem with calling my array.....
i want to make a game like hangman which has categories...
i make string array for every category....

here is some of my code in game.java

```
public static final String KEY_CATEGORY = "package.name.category";
public static int CATEGORY_CITY = 0;
public static int CATEGORY_ANIMAL = 1;
public static int CATEGORY_FRUIT = 2;
public static int CATEGORY_PLANT = 3;

private void setWordByCategory() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    cat = getIntent().getIntExtra(KEY_CATEGORY,CATEGORY_CITY);
    mysteryWord = getWord (cat);

private String getWord(int cat) {
    if (cat == CATEGORY_CITY) {
        String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cityarray);
        String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
    } else if (cat == CATEGORY_ANIMAL) {
        String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.animalarray);
        String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
    } else if (cat == CATEGORY_FRUIT) {
        String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruitarray);
        String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
    } else if (cat == CATEGORY_PLANT) {
        String[] array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.plantarray);
        String randomStr = array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
    }
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mysteryWord;
}
```

what is wrong with my code?
it said "the value of RandomStr is not used"...
it shows no error..
but when i try to run it, it just force close after pick a category...
cant go to game.java

Comment: @user2336315 then how to fix it..? sorry i just new in java... can you help me sir..?

Comment: show your crash log ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The scope or your variable are only visible in their if/else block. You're doing nothing in them, and hence the warning;

Change your method like this :

```
private String getWord(int cat) {
    String [] array = null;
    if (cat == CATEGORY_CITY) {
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.cityarray);
    } else if (cat == CATEGORY_ANIMAL) {
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.animalarray);
    } else if (cat == CATEGORY_FRUIT) {
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.fruitarray);
    } else if (cat == CATEGORY_PLANT) {
        array = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.plantarray);
    }

    return array == null ? "ERROR" : array[new Random().nextInt(array.length)];
}
```

For the force close, show your logcat.